# Can I restore a Win10 bootloader with a Win7 DVD?

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, mbr, system-recovery

My friend's struggling with a Windows 10 installation he cloned from a HDD to a SSD. He tried to create a Win10 stick but it failed. So I would like to know if it's possible to restore the MBR/Bootloader with a Windows 7 (or Hiren's Boot CD)?

I already heard of EasyBCD, but I'm afraid that I mess up with the HDD which still works and is bootable.

Comment: No; Just download the Windows 10 .ISO

Comment: We already tested using the Windows 10 tool from MS.

Comment: If you want to use Hiren's boot cd, you can select Parted Magic and then Clonezilla. Do a disk to disk copy from the HDD to the SSD.  Then make sure the SSD comes first in the boot order, reboot, and it should work.